# how to send inter-operator sms via GSM/LTE module

Tags: networking, sms, gsm, at-command, hyperterminal

I am using a GSM/LTE module (EC21 Quectel) to send and recieve sms with  HyperTerminal application on computer by at-commands.

I can send sms to devices with the same operator (intra-operator), but not to any other operator (inter-operator).

I can even recieve sms from other operators on my module, but when i try sending to them i get error:

***the first number has the same operator as my module's simcard and the second one has a different operator***
[image: the first number has the same operator as my module's simcard and the second one has a different operator]

So does anybody know how to send an inter-operator sms?

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was because of my simcard monetary charge. for sending sms to diffrent operator, the network would charge me and my sim balance was zero. so i would get this "unknown error". so i charged my sim balance and the problem solved.